# javax.validation ORDER of failures-entries as result of validate method

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I'm using `javax.validation` for `JSR-303` bean validation.

After calling the validate method, I go through the result and do someting in my GUI(for example highlighting the failed fields in my form).

My question here:

**MyBean.java**

```
public class MyBean {

    @Size(min = 1, message = "Please insert title")
    private String title;

    @Size(min = 1, message = "Please insert author")
    private String author;

    @Size(min = 1, message = "Please insert publisher")
    private String publisher;

    // ... something
}
```

**My Validation method:**

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyBean>> failures = this.validator.validate(bean);
```

After that, I iterate over my failures object:

```
for (ConstraintViolation<MyBean> constraintViolation : failures) {
        propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
        if (propertyPath.equals("title")) {
            Color bg = new Color(242, 242, 251);
            this.txtTitle.setBackground(bg);

        }
        // some else if for other attributes (for example: author)
        // add error to all error messages
        errorMessage += constraintViolation.getMessage();
}
```

Now my problem is: The **order** of these objects in the failures set. It is not correct.
Is there a solution to get the correct order?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

A Set is not guaranted to keep its elements ordered (HashSet don't). Hence you shouldn't rely on this order and you will probably have to test each ConstraintViolation in order to apply the right process to it for example using constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().

But ideally you should not have to know which failure you are processing, you normally only need to know it's a ConstraintViolation and apply a general method to it

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you wrote, but the problem is still: The errormessage gets unordered, and thats not professional. (And also I want to set a focus on the first textfield of the form with an error occured.)

Comment: So I think it then depends on you UI technology, which should itself rely on the Beans Validation implementation you chose. Either search for JSR 303 integration with your UI framework or tell us more about your context and your needs

Answer (score 0):

It is actually allowed for a Bean Validation implementation to evaluate constraints in any order, unless an order is required due to a group sequence. This is the reason why you get a set of _ConstraintViolation_s in the first place.